# Better approach to extend On-premises MS Active Directory on AWS Cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I want to extend my on-prem MS AD on AWS cloud. One approach is to create AWS managed MS AD on AWS cloud and create a trust relationship between both the cloud and on-prem AD and use the AWS managed AD's DNS IP as DNS setup for the EC2 instances. What would be other better approach to extend my on-prem AD on AWS cloud to access the EC2 servers that are associated with the on-prem domain.

Answer (score 0):

have you taken a look at the AD connector:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/directory_ad_connector.html
This appears to do many of the things you are looking for and is probably easier to set up.